# function not running in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

For some reason, in node.js, the code is not running in order. It is running the console.log(data2) before even retrieving the data from function2.
I am assuming it is because node.js runs asynchronously. However, I am not too sure how to fix it.
Thanks for all the help in advance

```
function function1(app){
    app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
        const url = `url1`;
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                var data2 = function2(data.id);
                console.log(data2); //undefined  
                res.send(profileData);
            }
        });
    })
}

function function2(id){
    const url = `url2/${id}`;
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(data); //output correct data
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: You are right. Because it works async, it actually runs in order without waiting for response of your function2. Node.js just calls your function2 and moves on, if you want it to wait or use the data that comes from an async call, you should use promises (async/await or then) or callbacks. See the comment above and i would also recommend you to look at Promise.all.

Comment: Bit of a misconception that *node* runs asynchronously...it is the specific request methods you are using that do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function function1(app){
    app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
        const url = `url1`;
        request(url, async function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                var data2 = await function2(data.id);
                console.log(data2); //undefined  
                res.send(profileData);
            }
        });
    })
}


function function2(id) {
  const url = `url2/${id}`;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
      if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      } else {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I get an error "await is only valid in async function", even tough I put async behind the function

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling `function2()` just before outputting `console.log(data2)`. The latter gets executed immediately, while the former has to make a server request. Pass `data2` to `function2()` instead and output it after you output the result from `function2()`

```
function function1(app){
    app.post('/test', (req, res, next) => {
        const url = `url1`;
        request(url, function(error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(body);
                var data2 = function2(data.id, data2);
                res.send(profileData);
            }
        });
    })
}

function function2(id, data2){
    const url = `url2/${id}`;
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(data); //output correct data
            console.log(data2); //undefined  
            return data;
        }
    });
}
```